# How can you set a data frames column to be an extractable pattern in R?

Tags: r, str-replace, text-extraction

I'm attempting the following:
* extract a character pattern from a merged column in a df
* create df column with extracted pattern
* remove extracted pattern from merged column

Lets say you have this example data frame

```
Col1 <- c("a1 b1 c1","a2 b2 c2","a3 b3 c3","a4 b4 c4")
dat <- data.frame(Col1)
dat

       Col1
   1 a1 b1 c1
   2 a2 b2 c2
   3 a3 b3 c3
   4 a4 b4 c4
```

How can you extract all elements containing "a" into another column and then remove the element from Col1 to get:

```
   dat

     Col1   Col2
   1 b1 c1   a1
   2 b2 c2   a2
   3 b3 c3   a3
   4 b4 c4   a4
```

I have been using the stringr package in R and using str_extract for extracting patterns. Is there a way to set a data frames column to be a pattern to be replaced in the merged column?

Comment: regex can do a lot. You can learn and experiment with online regex test website like regex101.com  You can see explanation of your regex, test the regex result easily.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to extract the 'a' followed by numbers with `str_extract` (from `stringr`) and the rest of the characters with `sub` and create a `data.frame`

```
library(stringr)
data.frame(Col1 = sub("^\\S+\\s+", "", dat$Col1), Col2=str_extract(dat$Col, "a\\d+"))
#  Col1 Col2
#1 b1 c1   a1
#2 b2 c2   a2
#3 b3 c3   a3
#4 b4 c4   a4
```

---

Or a `base R` approach assuming that the 'a' followed by numbers(`\\d+`) occur at the beginning of the string, we use `sub` to match 'a' followed by one or more digits, capture it as a a group (`(a\\d+)`) followed by one more space (`\\s+`) and then the second capture group with the rest of the characters (`(.*`).  We replace it with backreference for the capture groups separated by `,`.  This can be used in `read.table/read.csv` to create the new data.frame.

```
read.table(text=sub("(a\\d+)\\s+(.*)", "\\1,\\2", dat$Col1), 
       sep=",", col.names=c("Col1", "Col2"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

---

Or with `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
extract(dat, Col1, into = c("Col1", "Col2"), "(a\\d+)\\s+(.*)")
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
 a.pat <- ([a]{1})([0-9]{1}) # Identify/create pattern to be extracted

 dat$Col2 <- str_extract(dat$Col1,a.pat) # Create a new column with extracted pattern

 # Now we will seperate and convert Col2 into a pattern
 Col2.pat <- as.list(dat$Col2) # Separate column pattern from df as list 
 Col2.pat <- as.character(Col2.pat) # set Col2 as a character string

 dat$Col1 <- str_replace(dat$Col1,Col2.pat,"") # Remove element from merged column
```